# Pod init not working after updating terminal(Some popup came to change to ZSH)

Tags: ios, macos

I don't know what went wrong, everything was working fine until terminal showed me Popup and my default terminal which used to open with nileshjha@Nileshs-MacBook-Air $ changed to nileshjha@Nileshs-MacBook-Air ~ % .. And after that pod stopped working. I tried all ways to change it back to previous . But didn't succeed. 
Now when i am doing pod init , I am getting this error.

zsh: /usr/local/bin/pod: bad interpreter: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: no such file or directory

Can you please help me out of this.

Answer (score 2):

I have MacOS Catalina, and am trying to update cocoa pods.

I received an error when I tried running `pod update`

Here is the error message:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Next, I ran `sudo gem install cocoapods`

That was all that was needed.  `pod update` worked fine after that

Answer (score 0):

The same initial issue occurred when attempting to setup GoogleMaps in a Flutter app after running pod install on the iOS directory.

Running `pod install` the following error appeared:

```
zsh: /usr/local/bin/pod: bad interpreter: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: no such file or directory
```

Next, after running `sudo gem install cocoapods`, that resulted in another error:

ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

[kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916845/kevin) recommends installing Xcode Developer Tools running:

```
xcode-select --install
```

and while highlighting the need to install the tools, the system again produced the same error as before when running the `pod install` command.

Refresing the tools by removing and reinstalling them became the next target. The tools are removed with the following command:

```
rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

And again installing the xcode developer tools using:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then, `sudo gem install cocoapods` and `pod install` ran successfully.